# Provide sub-admin menu accessibility for whole module and a number of modules in a single go

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer, permissions, user-roles

I am running Magento CE 1.9.2.1 in my site which has many third-party modules installed having ton of admin menu items of their own.

Now I have created a sub-admin role, which is not as control-freak as Main admin role, but now I want to assign access to every third-party module I have installed, to the newly created "SubAdmin" role.

I have already provided the "acl" tags in my config.xml files of all third-party modules. Now I have to add following code to every adminhtml controller of every thirdparty module for making it accessible for every subadmin roles:

```
protected function _isAllowed() {
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('module/menualias');
}
```

Now I want to provide access to all modules from one Admin Observer file so I don't have to edit every controller of all modules. How can I do that or Can I even do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `custom module > etc` there are config.xml,system.xml is there. you also have to give permission from `system>permission` to your sub-admin.

also need have adminhtml.xml which contains bellow code and place it in `custom module > etc`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <custom translate="title" module="news">
            <title>Custom</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>
            <children>
                <news translate="title" module="news">
                    <title>Manage News</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>news/adminhtml_news</action>
                </news>
            </children>
        </custom>
    </menu>
    <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <news translate="title" module="news">
                                            <title>Manage News</title>
                                            <sort_order>51</sort_order>
                                        </news>
                                    </children>                         
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                        <custom translate="title" module="news">
                        <title>Custom Extention</title>
                        <sort_order>196</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <news translate="title" module="news">
                                <title>Manage News</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            </news>
                        </children>
                    </custom>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
</config>
```

**I hope this will help you.**